# Finding height of AVL tree?

Tags: python

I am writing a function to find height of node in an AVL tree and trying to implement it using python. This is the code I have written

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.height=0
        self.leftchild
        self.rightchild

class AVL(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def calcHeight(self,node):
        if not node:
            return -1

        return node.height
    
    def calcBalance(self,node):
        if not node:
            return 0

        return self.calcHeight(node.leftchild)-self.calcHeight(node.rightchild)
```

In this piece of code I am unable to understand if node.height is already a function defined in python  and how is the height returned when we call the function recursively in self.calcheight. Since we have not written anything else apart from node.height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AVL tree is a way of balancing a tree to ensure that the time to retrieve a node is approximately O(nlogn). The height of two subtrees can never be greater than one.

In the code above node.height is not an inbuilt function provided with Python.
You have defined a Node class, thus the node.height attribute refers to the height attribute in the Node class.

The calcHeight() method simply returns the height attribute of a constructed object of the Node class.

It is likely that the height is calculated and assigned to the height attribute when you insert a node into a binary tree.

```
"""
The BinaryTree node class
I have defined. 
"""
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def insert(self, node):
        # Call the private recursive insert method
        self._insert(self.root, node)

    """
    Inserts a node into the binary tree
    from current_node as the root.
    """
    def _insert(self, current_node, to_insert):
        if (current_node.data < to_insert.data):
            if (current_node.leftchild == None):
                current_node.leftchild = to_insert
            else:
                self._insert(current_node.leftchild, to_insert)
        else:
            if (current_node.rightchild == None):
                current_node.rightchild = to_insert
            else:
                self._insert(current_node.rightchild, to_insert)

        # Work out the hieght of the current node after the insertion
        left_child_height = 0
        right_child_height = 0

        if (current_node.leftchild):
            left_child_height = current_node.leftchild.height

        if (current_node.rightchild):
            right_child_height = current_node.rightchild.height
    
        # Calculate the height after the recursive call is made
        current_node.height = max(left_child_height,
                                  right_child_height) + 1

    """
    Simply demonstrates that the height of each node is correctly
    calculated.
    """
    def in_order_print(self, node):
        if (node.leftchild != None):
            self.in_order_print(node.leftchild)

        print("Node: " + str(node.data) + " Height: " + str(node.height))

        if (node.leftchild != None):
            self.in_order_print(node.rightchild)
```

Above I have defined an example of such a BinaryTree. The height is calculated after you insert the element. To understand how this works you need to understand the call stack in recursion. When you call a method the method call is placed onto a stack, when the method has finished executing it is popped off the stack.

Therefore in the _insert method above when the recursive call has finished (when the node has been placed at a leaf) we pop each recursive method call one by one. After popping off a method call we calculate the height by finding the greatest height of the left and right subtree and adding one.

Answer (score 0):

height is an attribute of Node. You can look at Object Oriented Programming to understand this. calcHeight on the other hand is a method of the class AVL. When calculating the balance of the tree, it's called to calculate the difference between the height of the right child of the node and the left child. This will allow to test whether the tree is balanced at that Node or not. Here's a detailed page about [AVL trees](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/). I'm assuming the height in your code changes whenever a new Node is inserted, although it's not shown.